# Creating a new variable and altering dependent variables in r using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, across

Let's say we have a df as follows:

```
A  B  C  D  E
1  1  0  0  1
0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  0  1
1  1  1  1  0
0  1  1  0  1
1  0  1  0  0
```

So I would like to make another variable `F` which says, *if the sum of A:D is greater than 1, F is 1 and A:D are 0*.

Additionally, If `E == 1`, then `F = 0`.

So here's how I wrote it but it's not working...

```
#Counter
df<- df %>% 
       mutate(case_count = A+B+C+D)

df$F <- ifelse(df$E == 1, 0,
              ifelse(df$case_count > 1, 
                     df$A == 0 & 
                     df$B == 0 &
                     df$C == 0 &
                     df$D == 0 &
                     df$F == 1, 0))
```

And the correct result here should then be

```
A  B  C  D  E  case_count F 
1  1  0  0  1           2 0
0  0  1  0  0           1 0
0  0  0  0  1           0 0
0  0  0  0  0           4 1
0  1  1  0  1           2 0
0  0  0  0  0           2 1
```

Comment: There's a logic problem here in the explanation and the output. Let's take the first row. The `case_count > 1` and `E = 1`. Why is `F = 0`?

Comment: @csgroen apoligies, it's e = 1, f =0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and the new functions `across` and `c_across`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    case_count = sum(c_across(A:D)),
    F_ = ifelse(E == 1, 0, ifelse(case_count > 1, 1, 0))
    ) %>% 
  mutate(across(A:D, ~ifelse(F_ == 1, 0, .)))
```

I named the new column `F_` instead of just `F` because the latter may be confused with the abbreviation for `FALSE`.

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Rowwise: 
#       A     B     C     D     E case_count    F_
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0     0     1          2     0
# 2     0     0     1     0     0          1     0
# 3     0     0     0     0     1          0     0
# 4     0     0     0     0     0          4     1
# 5     0     1     1     0     1          2     0
# 6     0     0     0     0     0          2     1
```

Comment: Interesting; this is obviously a reproducible example but the real df has more columns, which aren't relevant for this calc. Will c_across() allow me to just restrict this to just 4 columns without touching the others?

Comment: Yes, `across` and `c_across` will operate only on the selected columns. Reference for these new functions [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

Comment: Okay awesome, but what if the vars are not in a row? So like Var names A B C BANANA D. How could I get it to do what I need for just ABCD?

Comment: You simply specify them one by one: `c(A, B, C, D)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution (DF is your original data):

```
#Create index
DF$I1 <- rowSums(DF[,1:4])
DF[DF[,6]>1,1:4]<-0
#Create F
DF$F <- ifelse(DF$I1>1,1,0)
DF$F <- ifelse(DF$E==1,0,DF$F)

  A B C D E I1 F
1 0 0 0 0 1  2 0
2 0 0 1 0 0  1 0
3 0 0 0 0 1  0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0  4 1
5 0 0 0 0 1  2 0
6 0 0 0 0 0  2 1
```